# При нажатии на пункт меню происходит анимация, но не срабатывает clearInterval

Tags: setinterval, clearinterval

вот имеется такой код

```
/*------------ Скрол меню по клику на пункт ------------*/

if(nav) {
    nav.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var target = e.target;

        if(target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') {
            return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        SK.navigation.toggleToActiveLink(target);
    });
}
```

ну и сама функция

```
(function () {
    var me = {};

    /*------------ Проверка на наличие класса active ------------*/
    me.toggleToActiveLink = function(target) {

        var links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link');
        var showedSection = target.dataset.link;

        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {

            if(links[i].classList.contains('nav__link--active')) {
                links[i].classList.remove('nav__link--active')
            }

        }

        target.classList.add('nav__link--active');
        scrollToActiveSection(showedSection);
    };


    /*------------ Прокрутка до блока ------------*/
    function scrollToActiveSection(showedSection) {
        var section = document.querySelector('.' + showedSection);
        var coords = section.getBoundingClientRect();
        var animateTime = 0.4;

        var timerId = setInterval(function() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop < coords.top) {
                window.scrollBy(0, 10)
            } else {
                clearInterval(timerId); //остановка на нужном блоке
            }

        }, animateTime || 0.6);
    }

    SK.navigation = me;
}());
```

**SK** - объявление глобальной переменной
Подскажите плиз почему не срабатывает **clearInterval**

может быть проблема с **window.scrollBy(0, 10)**? просто если создавать прокрутку к блоку через **while** там вообще при нажатии на пункт все зависает и работать уже не возможно со странице

вот код самой меню 
nav.nav.
 - var items = ['Home', 'About us', 'Our Approach', 'Our work'] 
 - var dataItems = ['header', 'about', 'approach', 'work'] 
     each item,
       key in items if item === 'Home'
         a.nav__link.nav__link--active.disc.l#(href="#" data-link=dataItems[key])= item 
       else a.nav__link.disc.l#(href="#" data-link=dataItems[key])= item

Comment: Как выражается несрабатывание? Если логгировать document.body.scrollTop, то что выведется?

Comment: не срабатывание выражается в том, что я нажимаю на пункт и происходит скрол в низ страницы, после чего я подымаюсь вверх а он все равно работает, пока не обновлю страницу. если логировать `document.body.scrollTop`, то в консоле выдает **вермя.748 0** и так до бесконечности пока не обновлюсь

Comment: Если логгировать document.body.scrollTop, то что выведется?

Comment: пототму что код в `else` не попадает